# Adding Custom screens in Web service endpoint

Tags: acumatica

I have added Custom screens to sales order which uses SO order custom fields and custom tables to capture setup related to the printing industry I am trying to add those screens in the web service endpoint. I am getting an error in Web service and web service endpoint.

How do I add those screens in web service?

**Web Service Error**
[image]

**Web Service End Point**
[image]

Comment: If you go to your custom screen and then in the upper right area of your custom screen (under tools or help depending on version) and click Web Service - do you get an error? if so you will need to resolve that before you can use it in a web service.

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: have you tried to look the first change exception logs for more detail? https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c9abc50f-4b48-4527-bdd4-0e2111176f14

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, it looks like the Endpoint Version is blank.  After creating a new Webservice Endpoint, you need to select the version from the lookup next to the Endpoint Name.

If the list of available endpoints is blank, there's some other issue going on.